# Android Studio: how to get a value from a site in WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, getelementbyid, getattribute

I want that my webbrowser (created with a WebView) Android app gets a value of a field in the browser..

I can put a value in a field..

```
browser.loadUrl("javascript:var uselessvar =document.getElementById('LoginForm_loginView_name').value='" + "Ciccio" + "';", null);
```

I can "click" a button..

```
browser.loadUrl("javascript:var uselessvar =document.getElementById('LoginForm_button_value_confirm').click();", null);
```

But I don't get a value form a field...

I tried everithing...

I think that this javascript could help me..

```
"javascript:var uselessvar =document.GetElementById('richiestaView.cognome').GetAttribute('value')"
```

but I don't know how to use it.

Please help me, this is my fisrt question... Excuse me for my english.